# How to construct html list by mapping with common id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

i'm facing problem to construct html list.

i'm expecting same result as shown by (Expected output(Static) Below:)

**Question**: `comm_id` having same value should be constructed 1 time

here is what i'm trying

```js
var list = [
  {'com_id':12,'text':'Apple'},
  {'com_id':12,'text':'Banana'},
  {'com_id':91,'text':'cake'},
  {'com_id':91,'text':'cup cake'},
];

var dataMap = {}, str = '';

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
   if(!dataMap[list[i]['com_id']]) {
      dataMap[list[i]['com_id']] = list[i];
      str += '<li>com_id:'+list[i]['com_id']+'    <span>'+list[i]['text']+'</span><span>'+list[i]['text']+'</span></li>';
   }
}

$('#dynamic_const').html(str);
```

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  margin:2px;
  background:#eee;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic_const">
  
</div>

<p>Expected output(Static) Below:</p>

<div id="static">
  <ul>
      <li>com_id:12      <span>Apple</span><span>Banana</span></li>
      <li>com_id:91      <span>cake</span><span>cup cake</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your if statement is going to ignore elements once that com_id exists in the dataMap

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = [
  {'com_id':12,'text':'Apple'},
  {'com_id':12,'text':'Banana'},
  {'com_id':91,'text':'cake'},
  {'com_id':91,'text':'cup cake'}
];

// group the text for each com_id
var reducedList = list.reduce( ( elements, element ) => {
  if ( !elements[ element.com_id ] ) {
    elements[ element.com_id ] = { com_id: element.com_id, text: [] }
  }
  
  elements[ element.com_id ].text.push( element.text );

  return elements;
}, {} );

console.log( reducedList );

// build the html

var newHTML = Object.values( reducedList ).map( element => {
  return `<li>com_id:${ element.com_id }<span>${ element.text.join( '</span><span>' ) }</span></li>`;
} );

console.log( newHTML );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to build your HTML you can use [Jquery $.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var html = '';
$.each(list, function(i, el){
    html += '<li>com_id:' + el.com_id + ' <span>' + el.text + '</span></li>';
});

$('#dynamic_const').html(html);
```